# i am getting error while accessing data from a json response

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting the error **undefined property data** while trying to access the data array returned from a json response.

```
{
    "data": [
        {---},
        {---}
    ],
    "links": {---},
    "meta": {---}
}
```

i am accessing the **data** like this,

```
$posts->data
```

just for the record i have tried `$posts->data[0]` and `"$posts["data"]` but none works.

Answer (score 4):

This is a json you can not access it using object/array methods.

1st you must decode your json object like:

```
 $posts = json_decode($posts);  //object output

 $posts = json_decode($posts,true); //array output
```

And then access it like:

```
 $posts->data     //object

 $posts['data']  //array
```

*Keep an eye on the nested `data` array. In order to access the values inside it you will have to loop around it.*

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention it before but i did try `json_decode()` but it gives the **error:json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string**

Comment: Then your output is not what you are showing us. If your `$posts` was the json you put in your question description json_decode would have worked.

Comment: it's exactly the same i have just removed the data inside each property just to make it more compact and easy to understand.

Comment: What you are saying is not possible, check your code. A json is a string and json_decode expects a string input. By getting the error you mentioned means that $posts is not a json string. Try to var_dump it but for sure your variable $posts does not hold a json string type value. Maybe you overwrite it ? Maybe it's null at the point you try to decode? Maybe it's an array or something but for sure it's not a json string

Comment: yeah i understand that, the response am getting was actually a json object, **ErrorException: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given**

Comment: Then do something like: `json_decode(json_encode($posts));` Again try to debug it and var_dump $posts before you decode it to see the type of your variable and what it actually looks like, cause it is not a json.

Comment: so now with `json_decode(json_encode($posts));` i am getting what's in the **data** but the other two properties **meta** and **links** are not there,i mean they just got disappeared. I am halfway to what i want from json which is `data` and the other half is the `links` ,but anyways thanks alot really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you get array in that response? Try to dump whole response and check what do you get.

Comment: i am getting json object in response but the arrow operator is not working when i try to access ``data`` property.

Comment: Could you paste it here?